# parse login through Facebook api 4.0 in android studio

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, parse-platform

My code is.

```
 private void facebook() {

 List<String> permissions = Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email");

    ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(this, permissions, new LogInCallback() {

        @Override
        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Log.e("Facebook", user + "    " + err.getMessage());

            if (user == null) {
                Log.e("MyApp", "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
            } else if (user.isNew()) {              

                Log.e("MyApp", "User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
            } else {
                userinfo(user);
                Log.e("MyApp", "User logged in through Facebook!");
            }
        }
    });

}
```

this code is always provided user is null..
I have use latest `Facebook SDK` is

`compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1'`

and `Parse` is  :  `Parse-1.9.1.jar`

and I have use `Android Studio`.
this method is call when click the button this method is work means facebook popup is open but it always provide user is null. This given is user is null but after refresh `parseuser` is not null.

Comment: Maby the user is null before you pass it to this function. Could you provide the code where you initialize the user?

Comment: Parse user is initialize an application class.

Comment: What I've found here: https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseUser.html it says  "ParseUser()
Constructs a new ParseUser with no data in it."

Comment: ya i know  but  parse is provide facebook login as a new user.. and I have seen this link but i have not found my answer..

Comment: I found a solution but he is [login a facebook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29642759/facebook-login-api-4-0-profile-getcurrentprofile-null-when-logged-in/29652674#29652674)  Same problem is my but he is  login through parse but how to solve

Comment: Let's try my solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29970253/3090526

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure but check the Key Hash settings on https://developers.facebook.com for your app. You need to have both key hashes for release and debug version set in app developer console. It might be that you've just set the key hash for the debug environment. For more see Setting a Release Key Hash. Hope it helps.

```
  ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(this, Arrays.asList("email", "user_photos", "public_profile", "user_friends")
            , new LogInCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
            if (user == null) {
                Toast.makeText(Form.this,"User Already logged up through Twitter!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (user.isNew()) {


            } else {

                Toast.makeText(Form.this,"User Already logged up through Facebook!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        }

    });
```

Add this also..

```
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
ParseFacebookUtils.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 }
```

this code is working perfect..

Comment: All setting is properly .. facebook are login in simple but when it use login through pase that is not work..

Answer (score 6):

Those are the steps I followed to do the signup / login / linking of users with ParseUsers according to Parse [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#fbusers) and some tips I found on the web. Please check that you didn't miss any step because I had the same problems with you and I had to do all the steps all over again:

- First, I went to [this](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=android) website and created a new application.
- I downloaded the Facebook SDK, I did the steps 4 and 5 and I added my package name and the default class name
- I added the key hashes:

Development Key:

> cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin keytool -exportcert -alias
>   androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\'YOUR NAME'.android\debug.keystore |
>   C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl base64

Release Key:

> cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin keytool -exportcert -alias
>   'NAME YOU GAVE AS ALIAS' -keystore  |
>   C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl base64

- In parse.com inside **Settings** and **Authentication**, I added in **Facebook Application** the **APP ID** that was created in Facebook.
- According to [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started), I did all the steps until **Using Login or Share** (including this).
- I went [here](https://developers.facebook.com/settings/developer/contact/sample-app/) and I added my development hash key.
- In the **Settings** of the application that I created in Facebook, I checked that in the Key Hashes field, there were both Development and Release Keys.
- I used the [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329250/the-developers-of-this-app-have-not-set-up-this-app-properly-for-facebook-login) from the correct answer to make my application live.
- I downloaded the latest SDK of Parse (**1.9.1**) from QuickStart because 1.8 it's not working.
- I added the new .jar file of the **SDK** and the **ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.9.1** inside the `libs` folder of my project and syncronized the **build.gradle** file.
- I added this line in `strings.xml` :
  `<string name="facebook_app_id">1421******</string>`

---

I added this in my `AndroidManifest.xml` inside Application tag:

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
    android:configChanges=
        "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
    android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

and this:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
    android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
```

---

In `build.gradle` of the app I added these inside the android because of some errors with `Diamond` (I am sorry I can't remember the exact error):

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

and I changed the SDK version to be numbers because of some error of undefined variables:

```
minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion 19
```

---

The related `dependencies` inside the same file:

```
compile fileTree(include: 'Parse-*.jar', dir: 'libs')
compile fileTree(include: 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4-*.jar', dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
```

---

- In the activity in which I want to do all those things with facebook I did the below things:

  ```
     Parse.initialize(this, "hoMaK", "wWV193mE");

      FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

      ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(getApplicationContext());

      final List<String> permissions = Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email");

      fb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
      {
          public void onClick(View view)
          {
              proDialog.show();

              ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(HomeActivity.this, permissions, new LogInCallback() {
                  @Override
                  public void done(final ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
                      if (user == null) {
                          Log.d("MyApp", "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");

                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Log-out from Facebook and try again please!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                          ParseUser.logOut();

                          proDialog.hide();
                      }
                      else if (user.isNew()) {
                          Log.d("MyApp", "User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");

                          if (!ParseFacebookUtils.isLinked(user)) {
                              ParseFacebookUtils.linkWithReadPermissionsInBackground(user, HomeActivity.this, permissions, new SaveCallback() {
                                  @Override
                                  public void done(ParseException ex) {
                                      if (ParseFacebookUtils.isLinked(user)) {
                                          Log.d("MyApp", "Woohoo, user logged in with Facebook!");

                                          proDialog.hide();
                                      }
                                  }
                              });
                          }
                          else{
                              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You can change your personal data in Settings tab!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          }
                      } else {
                          Log.d("MyApp", "User logged in through Facebook!");

                          if (!ParseFacebookUtils.isLinked(user)) {
                              ParseFacebookUtils.linkWithReadPermissionsInBackground(user, HomeActivity.this, permissions, new SaveCallback() {
                                  @Override
                                  public void done(ParseException ex) {
                                      if (ParseFacebookUtils.isLinked(user)) {
                                          Log.d("MyApp", "Woohoo, user logged in with Facebook!");

                                          proDialog.hide();
                                      }
                                  }
                              });
                          }
                          else{
                              proDialog.hide();
                          }
                      }
                  }
              });
          }
      });
  ```
- With all the above steps, I can sign up or login using my Facebook account and I am getting a new line in `_User` object in Parse.com in which I can change the data any time I want to (I handle it as a normal sign-up user)

Comment: You tried at least one time to connect with Facebook and you got an error from Facebook about the hash keys or about the user and after that you are always getting a null user?

Comment: when i connect the facebook and login then work correctly . but when login through parsefacebook then user is null in login time.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling your app and the facebook app too and try again?

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget to initialize your the ParseFacebookUtils class in your application class as it is presented in the docs:

```
ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(this);
```

Also pass on the onActivityResult to ParseFacebookUtils.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    ParseFacebookUtils.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Hope that helps ;).

Source: https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseFacebookUtils.html

Comment: Quite what I said, nice found.

Comment: this problem is facing when facebook is update in .. befour update it have properly work..

Comment: Did you check the facebook key hashes? Is everything ok there? Also check the API key.

Comment: I found a solution but he is [login a facebook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29642759/facebook-login-api-4-0-profile-getcurrentprofile-null-when-logged-in/29652674#29652674)  Same problem is my in login in parse but how to solve

Answer (score 1):

Let's try:

In your `build.gradle`

remove this line `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`,
then add these:

```
compile files('libs/Parse-1.9.1.jar')
compile files('libs/ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.9.1.jar')
```

that works perfectly for me and with this case :D

Answer (score 0):

Have you added Facebook activity into your Manifest?

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
```