# After parse login how i can i receive facebook data

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

I am making parse login in android successfully. But after these i have no data. I need name,birthdate,mail etc...

I tried some metods that i found in internet, but these method has been depreceted and couldn't find in facebook sdk.

My parse login code is below :

```
 Collection<String> permissions = new ArrayList<>();
    permissions.add("public_profile");
    permissions.add("email");
    permissions.add("user_birthday");
    // permissions.add("publish_actions");


    ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(activity, permissions, new LogInCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseUser parseUser, ParseException parseException) {

            if (parseException != null) {
                //succesfull login
            } else {
               //exceptions while logging
            }
        }
    });
```

After these, how can i achieve facebook information ?

Comment: check this answer.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29748256/parse-login-through-facebook-api-4-0-in-android-studio/29865703#29865703

Comment: @Destro this is the same, i am asking for what after this

Comment: Parse get automatic data in facebook.

Comment: if you get facebook data then create facebook login and then get all data in facebook.

Comment: @Destro i used your way, parse is just for login. I used parse and facebook methods together. That is not my imagination.

Comment: @Destro one more question for you =)[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34289663/add-read-and-publish-permission-together-to-parsefacebookutils

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
getfbinfo.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult result) {
                        Log.d("On result ", "On result");
                    //  finish();
                        AccessToken accessToken=result.getAccessToken();
                         GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                                    accessToken,
                                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onCompleted(
                                                JSONObject object,
                                                GraphResponse response) {
                                            Log.d("", "" + object+response);
                                            try {
                                                String userid = "";
                                                try {
                                                    userid = object.getString("id");
                                                } catch (Exception e1) {}
                                                String name = "";
                                                try {
                                                    name = object.getString("name");
                                                } catch (Exception e1) {}
                                                //final String email = object.getString("email");
                                                 String first_name = "";
                                                try {
                                                    first_name = object.getString("first_name");
                                                } catch (Exception e1) {}
                                                try {
                                                    String gender=object.getString("gender");
                                                } catch (Exception e1) {}
                                                String last_name;
                                                try {
                                                    last_name = object.getString("last_name");
                                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                                    last_name="";
                                                }
                                                try {
                                                    String link = object.getString("link");
                                                } catch (Exception e) {}
                                                //final String locale=object.getString("locale");
                                                //final String timezone=object.getString("timezone");
                                                //final String updated_time=object.getString("updated_time");
                                                //final String verified = object.getString("verified");



                                                        firstnameedittext.setText(first_name);
                                                        lastnameedittext.setText(last_name);



                                        }
                                    });
                            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday");
                           // parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link,birthday,first_name,gender,location");
                            request.setParameters(parameters);
                            request.executeAsync();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                         Log.d("Error ", "Error");

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        Log.d("cancle ", "cancle");

                    }
                });
```